# I am Unable to create cloud function triggers for multiple documents in firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

const collections = ['Leads', 'Customers','Branches','users'];

```
//Function to sync Firestore collections to typesense schema
 async function syncFirestoreToTypesense(companyId, collections) {
  console.log(`Syncing ${collections} for company ${companyId}`);
  admin.initializeApp();
  const firestore = admin.firestore();



  for (const collection of collections) {
    const firestoreCollection = firestore.collection(`Company/${companyId}/${collection}`);
    const typesenseCollection = typesenseClient.collections(`${companyId}.${collection}`);
    console.log(`Syncing ${collection} for company ${companyId}`);
    // Subscribe to Firestore events using onWrite
    exports[`syncFirestoreToTypesense_${companyId}_${collection}`] = functions.firestore
      .document(`Company/${companyId}/${collection}/{documentId}`)
      .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
        const documentId = context.params.documentId;
        const documentData = change.after.data();
        console.log(documentData);
        console.log(`got id - ${documentId}`);
        try {
          if (change.after.exists) {
            // Upsert document to Typesense
            await typesenseCollection.documents().upsert({
              ...documentData,
              id: documentId,
            });
            console.log(`Synced ${collection} document - ${documentId} for company ${companyId}`);
          } else {
            // Document removed, delete from Typesense
            await typesenseCollection.documents(documentId).delete();
            console.log(`Deleted ${collection} document ${documentId} for company ${companyId}`);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`Error syncing ${collection} document ${documentId} for company ${companyId}`, error);
        }
      });
    console.log(`Subscribed to ${collection} events for company ${companyId}`);
  }
}
```

It should create a cloud function for multiple collection in google console and whenever i make a change in firestore it should trigger the function and console.log should be run and add the data in typesense database also at same time ...
please help me out !

Answer (score 1):

Declaring your Cloud Functions in a `for (const collection of collections)` loop cannot work.

AFAIK there are two possible approaches:

#### 1. Declare a Cloud Function for each collection

```
exports syncFirestoreToTypesenseLeads = functions.firestore
  .document(`Company/{companyId}/Leads/{documentId}`)
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {...});

exports syncFirestoreToTypesenseCustomers = functions.firestore
  .document(`Company/{companyId}/Customers/{documentId}`)
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {...});

// ... And so on
```

Note that you can include the common internal Cloud Function business logic in a function, as follows:

```
async function typesenseCFBusinessLogic(...) {...};

exports syncFirestoreToTypesenseLeads = functions.firestore
  .document(`Company/{companyId}/Leads/{documentId}`)
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
       await typesenseCFBusinessLogic(...);
       return null;
  });

exports syncFirestoreToTypesenseCustomers = functions.firestore
  .document(`Company/{companyId}/Customers/{documentId}`)
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
       await typesenseCFBusinessLogic(...);
       return null;
  });

// ... And so on
```

#### 2. Declare a unique Cloud Function

The idea here is to declare a unique Cloud Function which is triggered for all the changes in all collections and checks if the document that triggered it is within one of the four Collections.

Something along the following lines:

```
exports syncFirestoreToTypesense = functions.firestore
  .document(`Company/{companyId}/{collId}/{documentId}`)
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
     const collections = ['Leads', 'Customers','Branches','users'];
     if (collections.includes(context.params.collId)) {
        // ... Business logic
      }
     return ...;
  });
```

This CF will be triggered anytime a document in your Firestore database is created, updated or deleted. If the doc is not under one of the desired collections the CF will just do nothing, but will count as an invocation. However note that the free tier for Cloud Functions allows 2M invocations a month and if you go over the 2M invocations you would the pay only $0.40/million (See [pricing documentation](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)).

Comment: Hey @AniketChavan, did you have the time to look at the proposed solutions?